# php-fpm not generating core dump files despite being configured to

Tags: php, centos7, php-fpm

I'm running Centos 7 with php-fpm 5.4. I'm encountering a (signal 11) SIGSEGV error in my php-fpm error logs and want to debug it.

I've followed the advice of [php5 fpm: how do you generate core dump from segfault?](https://serverfault.com/questions/304947/php5-fpm-how-do-you-generate-core-dump-from-segfault) but php-fpm is still not even attempting to generate core dumps. From the php-fpm error log:

`WARNING: [pool website.com] child 26953 exited on signal 11 (SIGSEGV) after 0.931337 seconds from start`

If a core dump had been generated, it would read `(SEGSEGV - core dumped)` but it doesn't.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to solve this problem with the following:

1. Added to /etc/systemd/system.conf file:

`DefaultLimitCORE=infinity`

2. Changed the kernel.core_pattern:

`sysctl kernel.core_pattern='| /usr/lib/systemd/systemd-coredump %p %u %g %s %t %c %e'`

3. Reloaded systemd configuration:

`systemctl daemon-reload`

As an extra step for php-fpm, the following directive needs to be set in the individual php-fpm pool files you want to monitor:

rlimit_core = unlimited

The default directory for the systemd-coredump program is `/var/lib/systemd/coredump` so you should see dump files generated here.

Answer (score 1):

I also had trouble with this. It seems that on centos the master `php-fpm` process is launched with root privileges, which then launches the individual pools with reduced privileges (user `php-fpm` on centos by default).

The stumbling block for me, and I suspect for you too, is that if a process has changed it's own execution privileges, it is not permitted to produce a core dump file unless `/proc/sys/fs/suid_dumpable` is set to allow this. See information about this kernel-level control [here](/proc/sys/fs/suid_dumpable).

Comment: For anyone finding this from a search, that link is dead but I had the same issue with `suid_dumpable` and fixed it with `sysctl fs.suid_dumpable=2` and restarting PHP-FPM.

Answer (score 0):

PHP-FPM switcher user before starting the pools. Hence I had to change `fs.suid_dumpable` to `1` as mentioned on

https://itnext.io/linux-processes-core-dumps-systemd-coredump-and-debian-cf2ddb11ef9e

```
sysctl -w fs.suid_dumpable=1
```